# Would user-set experience level be helpful in question tags?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags

Not as an automated tool, but if users could set their "experience level" within their favorite tags, it might be helpful to gauge the verbosity of answer needed.

I usually head into answering a question with only an assumption of the OP's understanding of the language/problem/framework/whatever. This regularly leads to me going back for numerous edits to add more detail (or lengthy discussions in comments).

The experience level could be shown in the tags on questions:

[image]

And people could recommend upping or downing someones experience (anonymous? earn exp vote points?)

[image]

Couldn't find any other discussion about this, so if there is and I missed it, apologies.

--

Comment: Wouldn't people either end up a "beginner" or an "expert"?

Comment: 95% of programmers think they are among the top 5%

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Well no, not really.

> it might be helpful to gauge the verbosity of answer needed.

That assumes you're answering the question for the OP only. Keep in mind however that we're trying to create a repository of quality content for the internet as a whole. So don't just answer with the OP in mind.

If you need a bit more content to create an answer that can be helpful to a wider range of developers (from beginner to expert) than the specific author of the question, go ahead, because you're doing everyone a favour. And with that in mind, I don't see a need for the feature proposed.

Comment: Makes perfect sense. Thanks.