# Does it make sense to keep downvoting a question that has been accepted?

Tags: discussion, reputation, questions, down-votes, meta

I asked an [honest question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/178174/would-user-set-experience-level-be-helpful-in-question-tags) yesterday (my second ever on meta), and was dissapointed albeit unsurprised to be met with 6 downvotes -- many of which came after I accepted the answer.

As soon as the question was answered, I tried to delete it since it was garnering so much negativity, but couldn't since there was an answer.

My sense is that I was being "punished" for trying to contribute; explaining why my question didn't make sense and me accepting that wasn't enough -- I also had to lose a bunch of points and then had the question closed as a dupe (which although is similar, is not an exact dupe).

Is the point to discourage people from asking questions? Or to prevent people from contributing? Or is it more a symptom people being jaded by many low-quality or inappropriate questions?

Either way, it seems to be a fine way to alienate potential contribution.

Comment: Note that downvotes are different on meta; http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences. Maybe people just disagreed with your [meta-tag:feature-request].

Comment: @Matt agh! Should have read the FAQ -- didn't realize that. Thanks! Now... should I delete or leave...

Comment: completely up to you. This question might attract a few downvotes once people realise you skipped the FAQ ;).

Comment: Too late. You can't delete it now. This question already has an upvoted answer.

Comment: Meta can be a harsh place, you'll find [this discussion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44188/how-do-i-participate-in-meta-stack-overflow-and-not-die-trying) interesting. :)

Comment: @Matt Heh -- fair enough :) Antony yeah I upvoted and will accept as soon as the timer runs out.

Comment: Just a quick point; just because you got 6 downvotes immediately doesn't mean you won't get 6 upvotes in an hours time (obviously, this depends on the question). I have one question at +10/-10 and I'm positive there's far greater disparities out there.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Think of Meta as an (extremely imperfect and often erratic) polling system.

A late downvote on a suggestion usually doesn't mean: "Ha! This new user needs to be shown his place"; much rather, it's "Oh, I don't like this idea at all. Let me cast a vote just to make it super clear I don't want this to ever be implemented."

You'll agree the OP's accepting an answer doesn't really have any bearing on this aspect of the system; it's (mostly) about polling on the suggestion itself, not you as a person.  Us Meta veterans get late downvotes on our suggestions all the time, too.

Comment: I like this answer. Let me cast a vote just to make it super clear I think this is a good answer.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, it makes sense.

The (major) point of a downvote is to signal to every future visitor that the question is somehow problematic. It has absolutely nothing to do with you personally, or with your meaningless<sup>1</sup> MSO reputation.

Furthermore, the traditional interpretation of downvotes on MSO is ["I disagree with this"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences). Well meaning and well phrased Meta questions may still get a bunch of downvotes, because people just disagree with the premise of the question. That's a bit confusing to newcomers, as most of us - through our experience on the main site - were trained to think that a downvote means "What new and bizarre kind of nonsense is this?".

That said, *sometimes* downvotes on MSO do mean "What new and bizarre kind of nonsense is this?", but that's (probably) not the case with your question.

<sub><sup>1</sup> MSO reputation is just a historical artefact; on every other Meta, your main site reputation is displayed instead, and Meta votes don't cost or earn you anything.</sub>